# Update foreign key id based on a column value in other table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-update

I have 4 tables in my PostgreSQL database: `class`, `lesson`, `subject` and `term`.

\d `class`:

```
  Column     |  Type   |                           Modifiers                           
---------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------
id           | integer | not null default nextval('class_id_seq'::regclass)
subject_id   | integer | not null
term_id      | integer | not null

Indexes:
    "class_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "class_subject_id_term_id_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (subject_id, term_id)
    "class_subject_id" btree (subject_id)
    "class_term_id" btree (term_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "class_subject_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (subject_id) REFERENCES subject(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "class_term_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (term_id) REFERENCES term(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Referenced by:
    TABLE "lesson" CONSTRAINT "lesson_class_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (class_id) REFERENCES class(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

\d `lesson`:

```
   Column    |         Type         |                          Modifiers                          
--------------+----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
id           | integer              | not null default nextval('lesson_id_seq'::regclass)
class_id     | integer              | not null

Indexes:
    "lesson_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "lesson_class_id" btree (class_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "lesson_class_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (class_id) REFERENCES class(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

\d `subject`:

```
    Column     |         Type          |                             Modifiers                             
----------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------
id             | integer               | not null default nextval('subject_id_seq'::regclass)
name           | character varying(50) | not null 

Indexes:
    "subject_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)   
Referenced by:
    TABLE "class" CONSTRAINT "class_subject_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (subject_id) REFERENCES subject(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

\d `term`:

```
 Column  |         Type         |                          Modifiers                           
----------+----------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------
id       | integer              | not null default nextval('term_id_seq'::regclass)
year     | integer              | not null
semester | character varying(1) | not null

Indexes:
    "term_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "term_year_semester_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (year, semester)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "class" CONSTRAINT "class_term_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (term_id) REFERENCES term(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

I populate the base with lesson's, classes' and subjects' data for this term, manually. On the next semester, however, I have to update classes' information, creating the same classes (they have the same subject) but referencing the new term. I managed to do that by inserting the classes' data on a temp table, updating the term and inserting them back to the original table. But now, the new classes have new id's that identifies them. Is there an automate way that I can update the foreign key values in lesson table to reference the new classes?

I used this piece of SQL code and it worked, but, as you can see, I needed to specify the class and subject id by myself. As I have a lot of classes and lessons, with specific subjects, I'd want to have some automatic update or iteration. Table *lesson2* is a temp table, with the same content as *lesson*:

```
update lesson2 set class_id = (
    select c.id from class c where c.id in (
        select id from class c where subject_id = 7) 
        and c.id <> class_id
    ) 
    where class_id = 12;
```

That is, in *class* table, for one particular subject, I have four rows like:

```
id   subject_id     term_id
3    7              2
5    10             2
```

and:

```
id     subject_id   term_id
210    7            3
211    10           3
```

In *lesson2* table, I have, for example, 3 rows like:

```
id    class_id
15    3           ...
16    5          ...
17    3           ...
```

How can I automatically update the first and third rows to be like:

```
id    class_id
15    210      ...
16    211      ...
17    210      ...
```

After that, I will re-insert the data on the original *lesson* table, excluding the id column.

Comment: 0) table definitions, including PK/FK. 1) your update looks like there are multiple tuples conforming to the where/join clause.

Comment: I take it `instance identificator` is supposed to mean `primary key`? If so, please update the question accordingly. Better yet, copy what you get in psql with `\d tbl`. (Click `edit`, left under your question.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do what you say you are trying to do.

Here is how I read your data:
A term defines a session such as a semester or quarter. Fall semester: 2013. Spring semester: 2014, etc.
A subject is the specific course of study: algebra, beginning piano, western civ 101.
A class defines the instances of each subject handled during a term. Algebra might be taught MWF at 10am for one hour, TTh at 3PM for 1 1/2 hours, and Sat at 10AM for 3 hours.
A lesson is each (gradable) division of a ... class? Are you sure it's shouldn't be subject? Does the MWF Algebra class have different lessons than the TTh Algebra class? It's possible. Depends on other attributes you are leaving out.

Either way, the next term starts. You enter a new Term row. You enter new classes. You would change subjects only if your school added a new subject or no longer teaches a subject. Lessons are tied to the class, so you have to enter new lessons for each new class. If lessons were tied to subjects, they would not change -- unless you restructured the way a subject was taught. But you *cannot* change the existing lessons that are being referred to by previous classes. Those lessons belong to those classes. New classes have to be issued their own lessons.

This may not be what you want to do, but it is the way you have designed the schema. And the database is wisely making it difficult for you to violate your own design. Good database!

After you've designed a particular schema, "walk" some representative data through it to see if it is really what you want to happen. In a well-designed database, the data should just fall into place, snap together like Leggos, right where you want it, with little or no effort. It will just go where it belongs. If you find yourself fighting the data, you've messed something up. Back up and try again.